# How to move a long string to a variable cobol

Tags: cobol

Hello im learning a cobol Online (CICS) well what im trying to do is to get 5 number after the trans name and 5 number after the first 5 number , then i must do add , sub , mul , div and display it

here's the code

```
*******************************************************  
DATA DIVISION.                                           
WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.                                 
01 INBOUND-MESSAGE                  PIC X(06).           
01 OUTBOUND-MESSAGE                 PIC X(80).           
01 WS-VARIABLE.                                          
   05 WS-NUM1                       PIC 9(5).            
   05 WS-NUM2                       PIC 9(5).            
   05 WS-ADD                        PIC 9(10).           
   05 WS-SUB                        PIC 9(10).           
   05 WS-MUL                        PIC 9(15).           
   05 WS-DIV                        PIC 9(15).           
*******************************************************  
PROCEDURE DIVISION.                                      
                                                         
****TERIMA DATA DARI LUAR ****                           
    EXEC CICS RECEIVE                                    
        INTO (INBOUND-MESSAGE)                           
    END-EXEC.                                            
      EXEC CICS RECEIVE                                    
          INTO (INBOUND-MESSAGE)                           
      END-EXEC.                                            
                                                           
      MOVE INBOUND-MESSAGE(5:5) TO WS-NUM1.                
      MOVE INBOUND-MESSAGE(10:5) TO WS-NUM2.               
      ADD WS-NUM1   TO WS-NUM2 GIVING WS-ADD.              
      SUBTRACT WS-NUM1   FROM WS-NUM2 GIVING WS-SUB.       
      MULTIPLY WS-NUM1 BY WS-NUM2 GIVING WS-MUL.           
      DIVIDE WS-NUM1 BY WS-NUM2 GIVING WS-DIV.             
      MOVE 'HASIL JUMLAH: ' WS-ADD ' HASIL KURANG: ' WS-SUB
           ' HASIL KALI: ' WS-MUL ' HASIL BAGI: ' WS-DIV   
      TO OUTBOUND-MESSAGE.                                 
      EXEC CICS SEND                                       
          FROM (OUTBOUND-MESSAGE)                          
          ERASE                                            
      END-EXEC.                                            
                                                           
      EXEC CICS RETURN                                     
      END-EXEC.
```

the problem is what i want to do is to display

```
Hasil jumlah : ....
Hasil kurang : ....
Hasil kali   : ....
hasil bagi   : ....
```

I got an error

> The "MOVE" statement was invalid.  Expected "TO", but found "WS-ADD".  The statement was discarded.

how should i fix it? thankyou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`MOVE`](https://open-cobol.sourceforge.io/faq/index.html#move) has only one source and possibly multiple targets.
You likely want to look for the [`STRING`](https://open-cobol.sourceforge.io/faq/index.html#string) statement instead.

Comment: Okay i already done it , can i ask about how to add a new line ?  because now im stuck because all the word are becoming 1 line i expected to be 4 lines ._.

Comment: If that answer worked for you, please accept it as answer.
When you want to have multiple lines you may could hack this with adding a line break `'\n'` in your string but more likely you want a different `EXEC CICS`, (actually this isn't a COBOL question then) and may create a new question if the documentation available to you hasn't the answer.